# how to partition a table without any progressive fields?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partitioning, row-number

I need to partition a table to get records in a range of values.

**I don't have a progressive field in the table.**

```
select [_Load_Timestamp], [COL_A], [COL_B], [COL_C], [COL_D], [COL_E], [COL_F]
from dbo.table
where ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [_Load_Timestamp], [COL_A], [COL_B], [COL_C]) between 500 and 1000;
```

Writing this code, it returns me the following error:

```
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.
```

The problem is the `ROW_NUMBER()` statement.

I can write the query like this but the problem is that I have to limit access to the table as much as possible as it is really slow.

```
select *
from ( 
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [_Load_Timestamp], [COL_A], [COL_B], [COL_C])) [id]
                ,[_Load_Timestamp], [COL_A], [COL_B], [COL_C], [COL_D], [COL_E], [COL_F]
        from dbo.table
     ) t
where t.id between 500 and 1000;
```

**Can anyone give me an alternative to get to the same goal?**

Comment: Is your goal to page through large resultsets (500 rows isn't really large unless a GUI is involved)? Is so, some searching on "sql server paging large datasets" will find discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [_Load_Timestamp], [COL_A], [COL_B], [COL_C])) [id], [_Load_Timestamp], [COL_A], [COL_B], [COL_C]
into #tmp_key
from dbo.table

create index IX_01 on #tmp_key on ([id])

select _b.*
from #tmp_key _a
join dbo.table _b on _a.id between 500 and 1000
and _a.[_Load_Timestamp] = _b.[_Load_Timestamp] 
and _a.[COL_A] = _b.[COL_A]
and _a...
```

The numbers 500 and 1000 will be dynamically set based on a loop that populated the table for me.

In any case, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with MyTable as  
    ( 
        select 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [_Load_Timestamp], [COL_A], [COL_B], [COL_C])) [id]
                ,[_Load_Timestamp], [COL_A], [COL_B], [COL_C], [COL_D], [COL_E], [COL_F]
        from dbo.table
     )
select  *
from MyTable
where id between 500 and 1000
;
```

Comment: This solution is the one I had already ruled out and was looking for an alternative.

Comment: No, it is not. This version with the CTE is similar to the one you think solved your problem with the temp. The difference, and the real reason the problem was solved,  might be the index you created over there.